# Wordpress: List Posts by Day, with that day being the title

Tags: wordpress, nested-loops

I've tried to do this before & failed, Maybe I just don't understand how it work, maybe someone has done this before and can help me out.

Building a website for a school with wordpress, they have classes for a subject and they list them via days of the week like so:

## Monday

- Maths
- English
- Science

## Tuesday

- Science

## Wednesday

- Maths
- History

When i'm building this, i'm using a custom post type called "classes", then i'm using custom post fields to input all the data, including when the class is, in time() format (Using a date picker)

This is how i echo the date/time:
`<?php echo(types_render_field("date-and-time", array("format"=>"l","arg2"=>"val2"))); ?>`

Now, currently this is my loop:

[GIST of Loop](https://gist.github.com/yratof/5851424)

But it's not working at all, it's listing the days, but it'll list the day several times, so if there are 4 posts on wednesday, it'll list wednesday, wednesday, wednesday, wednesday.

Which makes sense since it's just looping through the posts and echoing it's date.

Basically, I'm trying to write:

```
- loop days of the week 7 days ahead 
    - loop posts under the date heading based on custom field date
```

I was originally going to use scheduled posting for this, but scheduling posts in wordpress isn't the easiest for people who aren't computer literate, with custom fields, i'm able to style it & use the DATE PICKER that [TYPES](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) provides.

If anyone can help me out, that'd be fantastic!

Comment: Try to put `the_title` outside the loop.

Comment: Can you explain a little more to what that'd do?

Comment: `the_title()` prints the title of your current post/page

Comment: I know that much, but keeping it outside of the loop doesn't attach it to the loop at all, meaning that there isn't the constraint of the 'classes' post type query, it just displays the last 'post' title which is from the standard blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend managed to create a fantastic solution my problem, I'll post the code here & hopefully it'll help out someone in the future.

```
<?php 
 $begin = strtotime('Monday last week'); // Year . Week
 $end = $begin + (21 * 24 * 60 * 60);
 $week = -1;
 $day = -1;
 $table = FALSE;
 $this_week = date('W');

query_posts( 
array( 
    'post_type' => 'classes',               // Custom Post Type
    'order' => 'asc',                       // Order with earliest first
    'orderby' => 'wpcf-date-and-time',      // Order by the custom field
    'posts_per_page' => -1,                 // Show all
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-date-and-time',     // Key is the custom field
    'meta_value' => array($begin, $end),    // Array of the current month and next
    'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN',            // Between Being and End
    'author' => $author_id                  // Show only the author
    ) 
);                                          // Get posts between now and then

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
    $time = types_render_field("date-and-time", array("arg1"=>"val1","raw"=>"true")); // Your custom field
    $current_week = date('W', $time);
    $current_day = date('l', $time);
    if ($current_week > $week) {
        if ($table) {
            echo "</table>";
            $table = FALSE;
        }
        $week = $current_week;
        if ($week > $this_week)          { $week_str = 'Next week';}
        else if ($week < $this_week) { $week_str = 'Last week';}
        else                                                 { $week_str = 'This week';}
        echo '<h2 class="">' . $week_str . '</h2>';
    }
    if ($current_day != $day) {
        $day = $current_day;
        if ($table) {
            echo "</table>";
            $table = FALSE;
        }
        $table = TRUE;
        echo '<h3 class="">' . $day . '</h3>';
        echo '<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Location</td>
                        <td>Venue</td>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>age</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>';
    }
    ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo(types_render_field("location", array("arg1"=>"val1","arg2"=>"val2"))); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo(types_render_field("venue", array("arg1"=>"val1","arg2"=>"val2"))); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'age-group', '', ', ', '' ) ?></td>
</tr>   

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>We don't currently have any classes available on this day,
but we can <strong>book your child in for a class</strong>, please get in touch to organise this</p>
 <?php endif; wp_reset_query() ?>
```